# Laravel string conversion

Tags: php, laravel

is it possible in laravel to change string like this:

**"This Is String"** to **"this-is-string**" ?

In laravel doc. I have only found this:

$snake = snake_case('fooBar');

// foo_bar

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Why not just use PHP? See @Fabien's answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do it in Laravel though, you could call:

```
Str::slug('This Is String');
```

For more info visit API: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.Str.html#247-270

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for :) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Laravel but you can try this :

```
<?php 
$string = "This Is String"
$string = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $string)); // "this-is-string"
?>
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I couldn't type fast enough.

Comment: ok it's not laravel, but does the job :) thx for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
return Str::slug('This Is String');
```

> //this-is-string

doc : http://three.laravel.com/docs/strings / http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.Str.html#247-270